# multiple machine MySQL through Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have recently started using MySQL Workbench, hence I apologise if this is not the proper platform to ask this question. I tried to figure out the solution of my own, but could not find any appropriate one.

Here is my situation: At my workplace, we have a huge set of data about the operational and financial figures such as sales, employee, profit, etc for European companies spread over past 7-8 years and new data keeps coming regularly. However, the problem is we work from different remote locations, me in one city and the other two colleagues in a different city. Normally, we share our work files (.xls/.doc) etc through Dropbox. So, we thought of creating a database in MySQL wherein we all can submit/edit/add this data so that we can filter and analyse this data on several ways once the collection is complete. And we plan to use and access it thereafter. We believe that this is ease a lot of our work. So all I want to know is: can all three of us collaborate simultaeousy (in order to add or edit the data) through workbench Server administration, like the way we collaborate our work through Dropbox? I want to be the host (like the administrator) and then want to allow the access to my colleagues.

Thank you for your time and answer. You may also refer me to any site or link to read more about it.

Comment: What about shared MySQL server? You can all connect and work on that machine having shared data, procedures, views, etc.

Comment: If your MySQL database is accessible over the web (or through a corporate VPN) you can set up user access from wherever and establish connections from local copies of MySQL workbench. Be careful with security!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about what MySQL Workbench is.

MySQL workbench is just a data viewer and administration tool that connects to a MySQL server, there's no data "stored" in MySQL workbench, all the data is stored in the server.

MySQL workbench can:

- Connect to a MySQL server
- Send SQL instructions and show the results: You can create and drop databases, send SQL queries, create and execute stored procedures and functions... all assuming you have the right privileges.
- Perform administration tasks: You can create and drop users, grant or revoke permissions, etcétera

But the fact is: all is stored in a MySQL server... so the answer to your question is: Yes, you can work simmultaneously with your colleagues, if and only if all of you can connect to the same database server (as Mike W commented).

---

Addressing your comments, and clarifying more details:

MySQL is a database server. When you install it in a computer, all data is stored in that computer (aside from replication and other fine details). You **should** make regular backups of your data (MySQL has tools for that, one is `mysqldump`). If you want to access the data stored in your database server, you can do it:

1. By ussing the command-line client,
2. By using MySQL workbench or another GUI client program, or
3. By any program that can connect to the database server (via ODBC or specific libraries).

Focusing on MySQL Workbench, and addressing your specific question: If your machine breaks down, you can install the MySQL Server in any other machine, and load the backup into it. You will have to configure that new machine so that any of your coworkers can connect to it (that may imply that a new set of connection parameters is created).

Comment: Thanks, so if I have understood it correctly: my machine (since I will be the administrator) will work as the server, or in other words, it will host the database. And by giving access to my colleagues, they will be able to send/change/add data to this database.

Comment: If your machine has the MySQL server on which you all will be working, then yes. But it is not required; the database server may be remote to all of you, and you, as administrator, will be able connect to it with administrator privileges.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barranka. You cleared a lot of my doubts. I'd one more question. Will appreciate a lot if you could kindly answer when you get some free time. 1. The database we are planning to build is named as "Top5000". Now, suppose my hard disc get corrupted or my machine breaks down, and I install MySQL server in a new machine. And I dont remember connection name or any other details. Will I still be able to get access to Top5000? And if so, how? To be honest, I am still not completely clear with this "server administration" part. Hence this question. Thanks.